# Interceptor is not triggering

Tags: angular, interceptor

I have created an interceptor in angular but it is not working. This is what I have so far

**Interceptor:**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log('inter');
    req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer xx.yy.zz',
      },
    });
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

**app.module:**

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CuencasComponent } from './cuencas/cuencas.component';
import {InterceptorService} from './interceptor.service';
import {CuencasService} from './cuencas/cuencas.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CuencasComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    CuencasService,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: InterceptorService, multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Component:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CuencasService} from './cuencas.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cuencas',
  templateUrl: './cuencas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cuencas.component.css']
})
export class CuencasComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private cuencas: CuencasService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cuencas.getCuencas().subscribe(
        res => this.cuencas = res,
        err => console.log(err)
    );
  }

}
```

**Service:**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class CuencasService {

  private urlEndPoint = 'http://localhost:8080/cuenca/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCuencas(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.urlEndPoint)
      .pipe(map(
        results => results,
      ));
  }
}
```

When I execute the application the interceptor is called but it is not changing the headers. In the image the header Authorization is not replaced.

[image]

According to what I understand the interceptor must work correctly, please I need your help.

Comment: I try use "interceptor" but it not run. I have try some methods and don't run my code. I need pass my token in the headers

Comment: In this code I try pass Authorization: 'Bearer xx.yy.zz', like header

Comment: Is your Bearer token working outside Angular, for example, in Postman or Fiddler?

Comment: my Bearer token working well. I test it in Postman.

Comment: My Back-end only get null instead the token

Comment: Is the interceptor handling the requests at least? I mean, is the `console.log('inter');` printing the `inter` text? Just to start discarding problems.

Comment: I'm asking because [I've done](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/gms/blob/master/client/src/app/core/interceptor/security.interceptor.ts#L70) pretty much the same and it works like charm.

Comment: yes this console is for test my interceptor and this print normaly, but the interceptor not modify my headers

Comment: Hey, try to remove ```providedIn: 'root'```.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try appending headers:

```
 newReq = req.clone({
          headers: req.append("Authorization", 'Bearer xx.yy.zz')
      },
    });
 return next.handle(newReq);
```

This is because I am not sure if there are additional headers that are required to perform the proper call

Answer (score 0):

```
const TOKEN_HEADER_KEY = 'Authorization';

@Injectable()
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    let authReq = req;
//get the token from where you saved it (LocalStorage or SessionStorage)
    const token = this.token.getToken();
    if (token != null) {
        authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + token) });
    }
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

Try changing your interceptor like this.